# How to get byte[] from javafx imageView?

Tags: java, image, javafx, byte, processing

How do i get byte[] from javafx image/imageview class? I want to store my image as a Blob into my database.This is the method that i use for it

```
 public PreparedStatement prepareQuery(HSQLDBConnector connector) {
        try {
            Blob logoBlob = connector.connection.createBlob();
            logoBlob.setBytes(0,logo.getImage());//stuck  here
            for (int i = 0, a = 1; i < data.length; i++, a++) {

                connector.prepStatCreateProfile.setString(a, data[i]);

            }
            //store LOB

            connector.prepStatCreateProfile.setBlob(11, logoBlob);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connector.prepStatCreateProfile;
    }
```

**Is there a way to convert from my current object (imageview),image) into byte[]?, or shoud i start to think about using other class for my image/ alternatively  point to the location with reference and work with paths/urls?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this one:

```
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(logo.getImage(), null);
ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", s);
byte[] res  = s.toByteArray();
s.close(); //especially if you are using a different output stream.
```

should work depending on the logo class

you need to specify a format while writing and reading, and as far as I remember bmp is not supported so you will end up with a png byte array on the database

Comment: Thanks ,I was afraid i will have to use some swing way.Bud i think this will work alright bud isnt there any pure JavaFX way of doing this?Or is this fully recommended way for javafx to get byte[] from images?

Comment: yes there is a pure java fx solution, but it is uncharted territory for me.

Comment: I have a byte[] array. how can I load ImageView with this byte[].

Comment: The documentation of `Image.write` states : 

     This method does not close the provided OutputStream after the write operation has completed; it is the responsibility of the caller to close the stream, if desired. 

Which suggests to me it is necessary to either close the ByteArrayOutputStream or use a try-with-ressource block.

Comment: How to convert whole `ImageView` into byte array instead of `Image`?

Comment: why would you want that? a structure containing the image view properties on the side seems more appropriate. you could anyway create a serializable object containing all the imageview attributes, the image byte array and serialize that one. add a method to recreate the imageview and you're set.

Answer (score 8):

pure java fx solution *trace* ( == you will have to fill in missing points :)

```
Image i = logo.getImage();
PixelReader pr = i.getPixelReader();
PixelFormat f = pr.getPixelFormat();

WriteablePixelFromat wf = f.getIntArgbInstance(); //???

int[] buffer = new int[size as desumed from the format f, should be  i.width*i.height*4];

pr.getPixels(int 0, int 0, int i.width, i.height, wf, buffer, 0, 0);
```

Comment: if you used this,
WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer> wf = PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance();

then
pr.getPixels(0, 0, (int) (i.getWidth()), (int) i.getHeight(), wf, buffer, 0, (int)(4*i.getWidth()));  

scanlineStride needs to be 4*image.getwidth()

Comment: I don't understand, where is the blob output?

Comment: in the int[] buffer

Answer (score 3):

Lorenzo's answer is correct, this answer just examines efficiency and portability aspects.

Depending on the image type and storage requirements, it may be efficient to convert the image to a compressed format for storage, for example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(fxImage, null), "png", byteOutput);
Blob logoBlob = connector.connection.createBlob();
logoBlob.setBytes(0, byteOutput.toByteArray());
```

Another advantage of doing a conversion to a common format like png before persisting the image is that other programs which deal with the database would be able to read the image without trying to convert it from a JavaFX specific byte array storage format.