# How to get a byte from the image by getPixels

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to convert the image: `ImageView sentObject` into byte Array. I found the way to convert it in [ 1 ] so I wrote the code as below.

```
public void sendImage(ImageView sentObject)
　　　　　　　{
            PixelReader pixelReader=sentObject.getImage().getPixelReader();
            int width =(int) sentObject.getImage().getWidth();
            int height =(int) sentObject.getImage().getHeight();
            byte[] buffer=new byte[width*height*4];
            System.out.println("Byte1: "+buffer);
            try
                {
                pixelReader.getPixels(0,0,width,height,PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),buffer,0,width*4);
                System.out.println("Byte2: "+buffer);
                //pixel[i][j]=sentObject.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor(i,j);
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                out.write(buffer);
                out.flush();
                }
            catch(IOException IO)
                {
                IO.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The main point I want you to look is `getPixels` method. This method will convert an image into bytes and store those bytes in byte array (in my case, it is  `byte[] buffer`) However When I compiled and ran, it didn't seem to store the bytes for me. I put the debug statement: `System.out.println("Byte1: "+buffer);` and `System.out.println("Byte2: "+buffer);`Then the output is as below:

[image]

The `buffer` before and after activates `getPixels` are the same which means there are no pixels stored in the `buffer`. What should I do to store the pixels by `getPixels` method. And do I misunderstand anything?

Reference

[ 1 ] [Pure JavaFX: convert Image to bytes Array (+ opposit operation). What's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008675/pure-javafx-convert-image-to-bytes-array-opposit-operation-whats-wrong)

Comment: "The `buffer` before and after activates `getPixels` are the same which means there are no pixels stored in the `buffer`" - umm no. All you can tell is that it is still the same array: you are not looking at the content of the array at all.

Comment: How can I look at the content of the array?  James_D

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));`, for example (or just use a loop and show the first few elements, if you don't want the whole thing)