# Convert JavaFX Image object to byte array

Tags: image, javafx, arrays

We can create FX Image object by using

```
byte [] bytes = ------; //valid image in bytes
javafx.scene.image.Image image = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

And this can be set to an ImageView.

I need the opposite ***without*** converting it first to the ***BufferedImage*** (SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image,null)).

So that I can directly write the bytes to a file.

I've tried the following:

```
PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
    int width = (int)image.getWidth();
    int height = (int)image.getHeight();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[width * height * 4];
    pixelReader.getPixels(
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height,
            PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
            buffer,
            0,
            width * 4
    );
```

But the file generated by writing the **byte [] buffer** is not a valid image.

Any insights on this?

**EDIT:** The solutions given at [How to get byte[] from javafx imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038524/how-to-get-byte-from-javafx-imageview) cannot be applied to my question. As I've already mentioned clearly that I do not want to use converting it to BufferedImage using SwingFXUtils.
Moreover, I want to convert it to the byte array so that it can be written to an image file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get byte\[\] from javafx imageView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038524/how-to-get-byte-from-javafx-imageview)

Answer (score 7):

This is way later, but if anybody is wanting to find out, try this:

```
// Load the Image into a Java FX Image Object //

Image img = new Image(new FileInputStream("SomeImageFile.png") );

// Cache Width and Height to 'int's (because getWidth/getHeight return Double) and getPixels needs 'int's //

int w = (int)img.getWidth();
int h = (int)img.getHeight();

// Create a new Byte Buffer, but we'll use BGRA (1 byte for each channel) //

byte[] buf = new byte[w * h * 4];

/* Since you can get the output in whatever format with a WritablePixelFormat,
   we'll use an already created one for ease-of-use. */

img.getPixelReader().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), buf, 0, w * 4);

/* Second last parameter is byte offset you want to start in your buffer,
   and the last parameter is stride (in bytes) per line for your buffer. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ByteArrayInputStream` to create a JavaFX `Image` will only work using the original, unmodified image file bytes in the [supported formats](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) (bmp, jpg, gif, png).

After using `PixelReader` to read an `Image`, the byte array will contain raw image bytes that can only be written back to a `WritableImage` using the `PixelWriter`, which is why using `ByteArrayInputStream` produces an invalid image.

Below is a reproducible example using this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrLEf.png):

```
// Original image bytes
File file = new File("F:/Downloads/duke.png");
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
System.out.println(fileBytes.length);  // 17776 bytes
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
Image image = new Image(in);
ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
VBox pane = new VBox();
pane.getChildren().add(view);  // Works
in.close();

// PixelReader generated image bytes
int width = (int) image.getWidth();
int height = (int) image.getHeight();
byte[] pixelBytes = new byte[width * height * 4];
System.out.println(pixelBytes.length);  // 367928 bytes
image.getPixelReader().getPixels(0, 0, width, height,
        PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
        pixelBytes, 0, width * 4);
Image image2 = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(pixelBytes));
ImageView view2 = new ImageView(image2);
pane.getChildren().add(view2);  // Won't work

// PixelWriter generated image
WritableImage image3 = new WritableImage(width, height);
image3.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, width, height,
        PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
        pixelBytes, 0, width * 4);
ImageView view3 = new ImageView(image3);
pane.getChildren().add(view3);  // Works

Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

As a raw image format, the `PixelReader` image is much larger than the original, so if you are storing these images in a database and are concerned about space then you should try storing the original file bytes instead. Otherwise, the `SwingFXUtils` class can still be used to convert back to compressed format.

Another issue when writing back `PixelReader` image bytes is that you must somehow store the width and height, either as separate fields in the database or prepended/appended as extra bytes onto the image byte array.