# How to convert Image object to Base64 image in java?

Tags: javafx

I have an Image object created using

```
SnapshotParameters para = new SnapshotParameters();
para.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
Image img = myStackPane.snapshot(para, null);
```

Now, I want to convert it to Base64 image to put it into javafx WebView. But I did not find any method to do it. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `Image` to byte array such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24038735/6708868). Then use any Base64 library to encode. For example `Apache Commons`.

**EDIT**

```
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(logo.getImage(), null);
ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", s);
byte[] res  = s.toByteArray()
s.close();
Base64.encode(res);
```

Comment: can you give an example please?